# Why UserForm is "Not Responding" During Run Time in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm very new with VBA Excel and i only know the things as far as i need for this report formatting task.

I'm almost done with my task but when i run the program and start the progress, eventhough it works successfully, GUI is not responding for a minute. I share my code here, is something wrong with it? Can you suggest me any best-practice? I don't want it to freeze because it will look bad to my manager.

Just to make it clear, by "not responding" i mean it freezes on the screen and says "Not Responding" on it's windows frame and when i click on it, it gives a message like this:

[image]

*ps: the sheet that i get records has 20997 rows and 7 columns and i make some records to another sheet on same file sized and 20997 lines 23 columns. And my GUI is very simple, it has nothing but a CommandButton that starts the progress.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Well the code itself will probably work ok, though the style is, ahem, less than ideal. You say "UserForm": are you running this from a modal form? If so, you need to Hide the form in order to return to the workbook proper. The Form won't let you do anything except respond to it. Maybe at the end of your code you need Formname.Hide   ?

Comment: @VinnyRoe : Hi, Thanks for responding. I'm sorry i didn't understand what you mean by "modal form". Basically what i did is, after opening excel file, i pressed ALT+F11 than from the File menu, i choosed **Insert > User Form**.

But i think hiding form won't solve my problem because i may have bigger files in future and it may cause more problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i believe i found the best solution for this. (a) :)

Instead of using for loop in TheLoop subroutine, i removed the loop and changed it as in below. That makes it incredibly faster when i compare it with my first code eventhough i didn't disable event properties, and now it's not freezing.

```
Sub TheLoop()

    Cells(2, 1).Resize(20996) = "Defect"
    Cells(2, 3).Resize(20996) = "New Defect"
    Cells(2, 4).Resize(20996) = "3"
    Cells(2, 5).Resize(20996) = "2"
    Cells(2, 7).Resize(20996) = "Name Surname"
    Cells(2, 8).Resize(20996) = "Name Surname"
    Cells(2, 9).Resize(20996) = "FALSE"


    Cells(2, 10).Resize(20996) = " http://SERVER_NAME:8888/PROJECT_NAME/ "


    Cells(2, 12).Resize(20996) = "Software Quality"
    Cells(2, 13).Resize(20996) = "Unsigned"
    Cells(2, 14).Resize(20996) = "Software Quality"
    Cells(2, 15).Resize(20996) = "1"
    Cells(2, 16).Resize(20996) = "Name Surname"
    Cells(2, 18).Resize(20996) = "Software Quality"
    Cells(2, 20).Resize(20996) = "Development"
    Cells(2, 22).Resize(20996) = " TYPE YOUR MODULE'S NAME TO HERE"

End Sub
```

Comment: this a very specific solution to your code, actually a bypass rather then the correct solution to this type of problem, the correct solution is: writing DoEvents before the 'Next' statement in your loop

Comment: @Shaybc It's been long time since the last time i dealt with vba. DoEvent prevents freezing but is your method faster? with this solution i can do it instantly. If i don't misremember loop takes so much time for massive excel files

Answer (score 21):

You can prevent the freezing of excel window by putting

```
DoEvents
```

inside your loop.

Comment: pls, upvote this, thats the actual solution for most of freezing problems in VBA Forms

Comment: this is the best solution, you actually need to allow the Application to handle regular events (like click, window drag, redraw screen etc.), so since your code is working intensively and does not rest or relinquish control from time to time then the Application almost doesn't have the CPU time to handle this events, so my best practice is to find all the 'Next' and 'Loop' statements and write the 'DoEvents' one line before them, this way i can guarantee that each loop cycle will allow Application to handle events if it has some

Answer (score 4):

This happens because your procedure is very busy working.  For example your `Sub TheLoop()` is accessing 20995 x 16 times a cell to write on them a string.  The interaction VBA with Excel is slow.

There is a couple of things you can do to make the procedure faster.

1.Disable events handlers, screen updating and calculations before you run your procedure.  At the end of the procedure restore the settings again.

```
   'Disable'
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   '......  Code'

   'Enable'
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

2.You can optimize the `Sub TheLoop`.  Instead of writing immediately on the cells, write the values inside an array. After the array is full with the values, assign the values of the array to the range that you need.
 for example:

```
Dim ResultValues() As String
Dim j As Long

ReDim ResultValues(2 To 20997, 1 To 3)

For j = 2 To 20997
    ResultValues(j, 1) = "New Defect"
    ResultValues(j, 2) = "3"
    ResultValues(j, 3) = "2"
Next j

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheet")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(20997, 5)) = ResultValues
End With
```

**EDIT:**

Given that the columns between the ones that you modify are only text or empty cells, you can:

1. read the whole range into an array.
2. Then modify the array in the same way you are currently modifying cells.
3. After the modifications are done, dump the whole matrix in the range again.'

For example:

```
Sub TheLoop()
Dim arrRangeValues() as Variant
Dim j as Long

arrRangeValues= Range("A2:V20997").Value2

For j = 2 To 20997
    arrRangeValues(j, 1) = "Defect" 'Cells(row_index , column_index)'
    arrRangeValues(j, 3) = "New Defect"
    arrRangeValues(j, 4) = "3" ' this one also might be empty'
    arrRangeValues(j, 5) = "2" ' this one also might be empty'

    arrRangeValues(j, 7) = "Name Surname"
    arrRangeValues(j, 8) = arrRangeValues(j, 7)
    arrRangeValues(j, 16) = arrRangeValues(j, 7)
    ...
    arrRangeValues(j, 10) = " http://SERVER_NAME:8888/PROJECT_NAME/ "
Next j

Range("A2:V20997").Value2 = arrRangeValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. :)


When i applied your first advise i was looking like a bit faster but i don't think it's enough because my form still freezes


Then i decided to try your second advise, but eventhough i don't know about **Dim** and **ReDim** in VBA,  it seems like a necessary requirement a write my columns next-to-next in here

** `ReDim ResultValues(2 To 20997, 1 To 3)` **

but there are some other columns which are including nothing but a title and most of the those columns are between the columns that i record in TheLoop subroutine.

Comment: I would like to apply your solution but i don't want to write extra codes for moving columns to between others. Is there any other way that you can suggest me? :)

Comment: Does the cells in the columns 2,6,11,17,19,21 contain only text or blank spaces?

Comment: 3 of those columns are imported from another sheet in CostComplexity() sub routine, rest is blank except column titles

Answer (score 0):

I been tried with the Application.ScreenUpdating, Application.EnableEvents, Application.Calculation, DoEvents and Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")), and unfortunately the lasted options can not to resolve that problem, looking at the Microsoft WebPage say me if a program say me **"Not Responding"** is

1. For Security reasons and
2. Because is too heavy or complicated
3. Because the program don´t sent any FeedBack to user about to do.

In my case I tried showing and MsgBox to user with the finality to provide a FeedBack for the Win10 operative system and the customer, but is so **boring** that the user click yes, yes, yes, yes, ok, ok, ok, ok and viewing on others forums about VBA for MsgBox (automatly close), they suggest me that code `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").PopUp "Please Wait", 1` and tada!! I going to stop see the "Not Responding Message", and if the user don´t to press any click or button for disable the message don´t worry the program going to execute after the message close after 1 second in my case this solve me a lot of problems, i hope to help you, good lucky.