# UserForm - adding stop button

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro which is time consuming (it works for a few hours); that's why I want to add two things to my `UserForm`, to manually stopping the macro.

First button starts the macro. Let's assume that that code of this macro looks like:

```
For i = 1 to 10000
    DoEvents 
    If isCancelled Then Exit Sub
Next i
```

I was thinking about adding an additional "Stop" button, which changes `isCancelled` from `False` to `True`, but the button is locked and can't be clicked during macro execution. Is there any way to enable this button? Or maybe there is a better way to manually stop the macro?

Comment: Yes this is possible

Comment: Thank you :) You all helped me a lot with this problem!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, yes this is possible and can be illustrated with a simple example. This is essentially the type of code you alluded to.

Assume your UserForm has two buttons, which start (or resume) and stop the procedure respectively.

```
Option Explicit
Public isCancelled As Boolean
Public iVal As Long
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
If iVal = 0 Then iVal = 1  'Allows the user to resume if it's been "stopped"
isCancelled = False
For i = iVal To 100000
    iVal = i
    If i Mod 1000 = 1 Then
        Debug.Print i
    End If
    If isCancelled Then
        GoTo EarlyExit
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If

Next
EarlyExit:
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    isCancelled = True
End Sub
```

Of course, implementing the "continuation" option which I did here is a neat little trick, but it may be increasingly complicated depending on the complexity of your procedure, it's dependencies, etc. and if your form is displayed `vbModeless` you'll need to ensure the user doesn't alter the environment in such a manner as to introduce a runtime error, etc.

You may also look to optimize your procedure if runtime is several *hours*.

Comment: @Nakahed if this has solved the question, do consider marking it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `DoEvents` in the loop to catch user responds.

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606651/why-userform-is-not-responding-during-run-time-in-vba-excel), which might help you as well.